# How can I train a CNN on raw numbers?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, numpy

I am trying to make a binary classification using Keras' Conv2D classes based on [this blog](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html). I have many files with a matrix of floating point numbers in each one (these matrices are not pixels values). They are stored in separate folders that are named after each class. The problem is that don't really know:

- can or should I treat these matrices as images?
- Each matrix is of constant rows number and varying number of columns and I don't know how to feed a CNN with such data, but to transform it to an image and then resize. I found this [How to train a CNN with non-squared data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299171/how-to-train-a-cnn-with-non-squared-data) but I don't know how to apply this.

The matrices are coefficients values. You can think of those values as if you were trying to make a height map of some piece of land. You'd make a mesh out if this land, measure the height (let's say that you take 300 m.a.s.l as a reference point) in each corner of each square of the mesh and then put that value into an array. At the end, if you plot that array you'd obtain a rough 3D land map. Then you feed a CNN with that data and make a binary classification whether such a terrain is hilly or lowland. I can transform that data into an image (although I think I'll lose some relevant information then) and then feed a CNN with these images.

What I've done so far

I grabbed some lines from `keras.preprocessing.image.NumpyArrayIterator` and `keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator` classes and combined them together so that I could read Matlab's `.mat` files:

```
import multiprocessing.pool
import os
from functools import partial
import h5py
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K
from keras.preprocessing.image import Iterator, _count_valid_files_in_directory, _list_valid_filenames_in_directory, \
    ImageDataGenerator


class MatFileIterGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator()

    def flow_from_directory(self, directory, variable,
                            target_size=(256, 256), classes=None, class_mode='categorical',
                            batch_size=32, shuffle=True, seed=None,
                            follow_links=False,
                            interpolation='nearest'):
        return MatFilesIterator(
            directory, variable, self.image_data_generator,
            classes=classes, class_mode=class_mode,
            batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle, seed=seed,
            follow_links=follow_links,
            interpolation=interpolation)


class MatFilesIterator(Iterator):

    def __init__(self, directory, variable, image_data_generator, classes=None, class_mode="categorical",
                 batch_size=32, shuffle=True, seed=None, interpolation='nearest', follow_links=False):

        self.variable = variable
        self.directory = directory
        self.image_data_generator = image_data_generator
        self.data_format = K.image_data_format()
        self.classes = classes

        if class_mode not in {'categorical', 'binary', 'sparse',
                              'input', None}:
            raise ValueError('Invalid class_mode:', class_mode,
                             '; expected one of "categorical", '
                             '"binary", "sparse", "input"'
                             ' or None.')
        self.class_mode = class_mode
        self.interpolation = interpolation

        white_list_formats = {"mat"}

        # first, count the number of samples and classes
        self.samples = 0

        if not classes:
            classes = []
            for subdir in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
                if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, subdir)):
                    classes.append(subdir)
        self.num_classes = len(classes)
        self.class_indices = dict(zip(classes, range(len(classes))))

        pool = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool()
        function_partial = partial(_count_valid_files_in_directory,
                                   white_list_formats=white_list_formats,
                                   follow_links=follow_links)
        self.samples = sum(pool.map(function_partial,
                                    (os.path.join(directory, subdir)
                                     for subdir in classes)))

        print('Found %d files belonging to %d classes.' % (self.samples, self.num_classes))

        # second, build an index of the images in the different class subfolders
        results = []

        self.filenames = []
        self.classes = np.zeros((self.samples,), dtype='int32')
        i = 0
        for dirpath in (os.path.join(directory, subdir) for subdir in classes):
            results.append(pool.apply_async(_list_valid_filenames_in_directory,
                                            (dirpath, white_list_formats,
                                             self.class_indices, follow_links)))
        for res in results:
            classes, filenames = res.get()
            self.classes[i:i + len(classes)] = classes
            self.filenames += filenames
            i += len(classes)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        super(MatFilesIterator, self).__init__(self.samples, batch_size, shuffle, seed)

    def _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array):

        # The script fails here with mentioned error
        # 60 is the mentioned constant row numbers
        batch_x = np.zeros(tuple([len(index_array)] + [60]), dtype=K.floatx())

        # build batch of numpy data
        for i, j in enumerate(index_array):
            fname = self.filenames[j]
            arr = np.array(h5py.File(os.path.join(self.directory, fname), "r").get(self.variable))

            arr = self.image_data_generator.random_transform(arr.astype(K.floatx()))
            arr = self.image_data_generator.standardize(arr)
            batch_x[i] = arr

        # build batch of labels
        if self.class_mode == 'input':
            batch_y = batch_x.copy()
        elif self.class_mode == 'sparse':
            batch_y = self.classes[index_array]
        elif self.class_mode == 'binary':
            batch_y = self.classes[index_array].astype(K.floatx())
        elif self.class_mode == 'categorical':
            batch_y = np.zeros((len(batch_x), self.num_classes), dtype=K.floatx())
            for i, label in enumerate(self.classes[index_array]):
                batch_y[i, label] = 1.
        else:
            return batch_x
        return batch_x, batch_y

    def next(self):
        """For python 2.x.

        # Returns
            The next batch.
        """
        with self.lock:
            index_array = next(self.index_generator)
        # The transformation of images is not under thread lock
        # so it can be done in parallel
        return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
```

I also coded simple CNN:

```
from keras.layers import Activation, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalMaxPooling2D, Dense, Dropout
from keras.models import Sequential

from matfileiter import MatFileIterGenerator


class CNN2D:

    def __init__(self):
        self._model = Sequential()

        self._model.add(Conv2D(60, (3, 3), input_shape=(60, None , 1)))
        self._model.add(Activation("relu"))
        self._model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))

        self._model.add(Conv2D(60, (3, 3)))
        self._model.add(Activation("relu"))
        self._model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))

        self._model.add(Conv2D(120, (3, 3)))
        self._model.add(Activation("relu"))
        self._model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))

        self._model.add(GlobalMaxPooling2D())
        self._model.add(Dense(120))
        self._model.add(Activation('relu'))
        self._model.add(Dropout(0.2)) 
        self._model.add(Dense(1))
        self._model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

        self._model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

    def createGenerators(self, train_path, variable, test_path, batch_size):
        train_datagen = MatFileIterGenerator()
        self._train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            train_path,
            variable,
            shuffle=True,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            class_mode="binary")

        test_datagen = MatFileIterGenerator()
        self._test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            test_path,
            variable,
            shuffle=True,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            class_mode="binary")

    def train_model(self, batch_size):
        self._model.fit_generator(
            self._train_generator,
            steps_per_epoch=2000 // batch_size,
            epochs=50,
            validation_data=self._test_generator,
            validation_steps=800 // batch_size,
            workers=2,
            use_multiprocessing=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cnn = CNN2D()
    cnn.createGenerators("/home/wilson/Documents/Data/_train_mat", "coeffs",
                         "/home/wilosn/Documents/Data/_eval_mat", 20)
    cnn.train_model(20)
```

Currently the scipt fails with an error `could not broadcast input array from shape (212,60) into shape (60)` where the 212 is columns number of some randomly selected file (shuffled). I can transform these matrices into images in Matlab and then use standard `DirectoryIterator` on them but I want to try raw numbers first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CNN architectures come with the inductive bias that information is mostly spatially localized. For example, in an image, changing a few pixel values in one corner of the image should not change my interpretation of the rest of the image, because of the spatial locality idea.

Since your data, a height-map, has the same property, it does make sense to use a CNN. I wouldn't say that this requires treating your data as an image. Rather, CNNs can operate on any N-D array, and both a matrix and an image are N-D arrays.

For variable input sizes, I suggest either resizing, cropping, or padding all your data to the same size.